# Maximum Number in Mountain Sequence

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Given a mountain sequence of n integers which increase firstly and then decrease, find the mountain top.

Example

Given nums = [1, 2, 4, 8, 6, 3] return 8

Given nums = [10, 9, 8, 7], return 10

```
class Solution:
     """
    @param nums: a mountain sequence which increase firstly and then decrease
    @return: then mountain top
    """
    def mountainSequence(self, nums):
        # write your code here
        if nums == []:
            return None
        if len(nums) <= 1:
            return nums[0]
        elif len(nums) <= 2:
            return max(nums[0], nums[1])


        for i in range(len(nums) -2):
            if nums[i] >= nums[i + 1]:
                return nums[i]
        return nums[-1]
```

it stuck at [3,5,3]. Based on my analysis, it went wrong after running the for loop. But I cannot figure it out why the for loop failed.

Comment: given you do not try a binary search (and maybe you should); why not just `max(nums)`?

Comment: 10 is not a mountain - it does not increase beforehand only decrease after

Comment: what about plateaus:   `7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 7` ?

Comment: actually its not allowed to use max(). I was just being lazy to write some more if. LOL

Comment: You're providing a wrong argument to the range function and the loop is missing one element. Change it for `range(len(nums) - 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be more efficient than your approach. it is a binary search customized for your use-case:

```
def top(lst):
    low = 0
    high = len(lst)
    while low != high:
        i = (high+low)//2
        if lst[i] < lst[i+1]:
            low = i+1
        else:
            high = i
    return low
```

it starts in the middle of the list and checks if the series is still increasing there. if it is it sets `low` and will ignore all indices below `low` for the rest of the algorithm. if the series decreases already, `high` is set to the current index and all the elements above are ignored. and so on... when `high == low` the algorithm terminates.

if you have two or more of the same elements at the maximum of your list (a plateau) the algorithm will not even terminate.

and i skipped the tests for empty lists or lists of length 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know the binary search solution. I just want to figure out what's wrong with my code. But thx!

Comment: you ignore the last element in your last `for` loop... should be `range(len(nums) - 1)` .

Comment: OMG! Gotcha! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This will get all triplets from your input, isolate all that are higher in the middle then left or right and return the one that is highest overall:

```
def get_mountain_top(seq):
    triplets = zip(seq, seq[1:], seq[2:])

    tops = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] < x[1] > x[2], triplets))

    if tops:
        # max not allowed, leverage sorted
        return sorted(tops, key = lambda x:x[1])[-1]
        # return max(tops,key = lambda x:x[1])

    return None


print(get_mountain_top([1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5]))
print(get_mountain_top([1,1,1]))
```

Output:

```
(6,7,6)
None
```

It does not handle plateaus.

Doku:

- [zip(), filter() and max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)